# JUnit test for void method containing a RestTemplate exchange call

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to write a Test class for one of my methods and I am new to JUnit. My class returns a void and has a `RestTemplate.exchange` call to an external endpoint.

I started off trying this, but this gives me a NullInsteadOfMockException.

```
    @Test
    public void service1test() throws IOException{

        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);

        Mockito.verify(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpMethod> any(), Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), Mockito.<Class<?>> any(), 
                    Mockito.<String, String> anyMap()));
    }
```

Here's my method that I want to write unit test for.

```
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;    

    public void service1(String a, String b) {

    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    try {

            headers.set("ID", ID);
            headers.set("secret", secret);

            System.out.println(docStoreUrl + itemID);
            HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

            ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Object.class);

            log.info("Status code for get : {}", response.getStatusCodeValue());

            if(response.getStatusCodeValue() == 200) {

                Object document = (Object) response.getBody();
                Class2.service2.execute(document);

            }
            else {
                log.info("Failed to retrieve document due to {}", response.getStatusCodeValue());
            }
}
```

I am new to JUnit testing and can't figure out how to write the Test class for this covering all the lines.

If this question is already answered, please point me to the appropriate URL.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a unit test or integration test. Try to add full test class

Comment: You wouldn't have that issue if the method would be implemented correctly. There is no point in Autowiring the RestTemplate and then still reassign the variable with a manually build RestTemplate.

Comment: This is the entire class to be tested, with the missing catch block.

Comment: I fixed the way I am initializing my restTemplate. The verify still gave me the same issue. Any help on how this should be approached would really work for me

Comment: Annotate your test class with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @Autowire the component you want to test, define what their behavioural dependencies will do (given(restTemplate.exchange(any(), ....).willReturn(whatever you need to make it work);, and then use the autowired component to call your method and test it returns what you expect.

Comment: You get the same issue, because you still don't call the `service1` method in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit late, but if anyone else falls over this:

This error will also occur, if you are using mockito wrong.
It should be:

```
Mockito.verify(restTemplate).exchange(Mockito.anyString() ...
```

Notice the closing bracket immediately after restTemplate, so exchange is called on top of mockito.